# How to do requestQuote in gunits

Tags: guidewire

Getting lacks quote and/or edit permission
Lacks advance permission

Trying to do requestQuote in gunit as below.               policyPeriod.SubmissionProcess.requestQuote(true,true)
Process I'm following is started test server and then ran the gunit, but not getting how to add specific permission through code, or is there anyway that we can achieve this. Suggestions please. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Gunit tests run in the context of the user you supply in the test code, so you're in control of the permissions the test executes with.  This is documented in the product documentation linked below (requires login credentials).  This area of the documentation also covers the use of Builders as Abhijay discusses in his answer.

https://docs.guidewire.com/cloud/testing/202310/isunittesting/testing/019-Using-test-data-builders/c_creating-objects-using-test-data-builder-classes.html

For convenience, here's a code sample.  The user specified in the "runWithNewBundle" (in this example, "su") will control the permissions the test will execute with.

```
gw.transaction.Transaction.runWithNewBundle( \ bundleObj -> {
var testUser = new UserContactBuilder()
    .withFirstName("Tom")
    .create(bundleObj)  } , "su" )
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. Will try the approach and check the documentation also.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't sufficient information or a full code snippet provided by you to decipher what's going wrong with your user. Typically this error is received when the user's roles do not contain one of the necessary system permissions. Ensure the user trying to quote has one of the bare minimum roles required to create a submission and quote it like a producer or underwriter role. Coming to GUnits, this isn't the ideal way to write tests or quote a submission. The recommended way is to use Builder classes. You need to check if your LOB has a Builder class that extends `SubmissionBuilderBase`. For example, you can refer to `PASubmissionBuilder` in OTB code. The ideal way to then do a quote is by using Builder methods as shown below

```
var issuedPeriod = new PASubmissionBuilder()
    .isQuoted()
    .isBound()
    .issuePolicy()
    .createAndCommit()
```

This will issue and commit a barebones PA policy. If you need more customization specific to your test case you can use the `withXXX` functions available in your builder class.

```
new PASubmissionBuilder()
        .withCoverage("XXX")
        .withVehicle(vehBuilder)
```

All Builder classes are chained together and available for consumption so if you want to start a submission from scratch, instantiate a `ContactBuilder` and `AccountBuilder` before moving on to job builders and lower-level objects like coverables and coverages.

Comment: Thanks abhijay. We do have all custom builders for our gunits, and I just posted the line of code which is giving error. Thanks for the solution provided, will try the option you gave. Thanks